# Reduce the width of Master of the MasterDetailPage for UWP in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, custom-renderer

I have created a Xamarin Application and in that I am required to reduce the width of the Master of the Master-Detail Page. 
I have followed an approach to create a UWP specific Custom Renderer. Below is my code :

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage), typeof(CustomMasterDetailRenderer))]
    namespace VirtusContactManager.App.UWP.Renderer
    {
        public class CustomMasterDetailRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage, MasterDetailControl>
        {
            MasterDetailControl control = new MasterDetailControl();
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                control.Width = 120;
                SetNativeControl(control);
            }
            protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                control.Width = 120;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have created the above Custom Renderer. The issue that I am facing is that I am unable to set the value of **control.Master** as it is a FrameworkElement and what I want is a Page. 
**control.Width** sets the width of the entire page instead of just the Master.

How should I set the **control.Master** to a page.
 If this approach is not correct , Kindly suggest a better way to reduce the width of Master page in UWP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we look at the `MasterDetailRenderer` that is being used in Xamarin Forms itself, you'll see that the actual control rendered is one of type `MasterDetailControl` ( https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/365a60e745d447992e870dd6272226e6b11ec275/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/MasterDetailControl.cs ).

Problem we face here, is that the actual property to change the size of the Master part is not accessibel because we can't get to the `SplitView` control inside the `MasterDetailControl`.
Normally you should use the `OpenPaneLenght` property to tweak the size ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.openpanelength#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_SplitView_OpenPaneLength ).

But! What you could do, is set that property inside the template that is being used for the `MasterDetailControl`! XAML will override any template if you provide your own at your app level.

So copy paste the XAML from the `MasterDetailControlStyle` ( https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/365a60e745d447992e870dd6272226e6b11ec275/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/MasterDetailControlStyle.xaml ) and paste it inside your App.Xaml in the UWP project inside a `ResourceDictionary` tag.
Last thing to do is add a value for the `OpenPaneLength` property of the `SplitView` control.

Like so - I've set it to 10 as example here to show that it works:

```
<Application
    x:Class="XFMasterDetailUWP.UWP.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XFMasterDetailUWP.UWP"
    xmlns:uwp="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="uwp:MasterDetailControl">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="uwp:MasterDetailControl">
                            <SplitView x:Name="SplitView"
                                       OpenPaneLength="10"
                                       IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsPaneOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMode="Overlay">
                                <SplitView.Pane>
```